# Unable to find activity Menu

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

I have two activities and i am calling the second activity (Menu) from mainactivity. Now probably it is confusing Menu with android.view.menu i get the following error all the time

```
11-04 08:05:39.225: E/AndroidRuntime(2845): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {info.saltnpepper.ordersmart2/android.view.Menu}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

my androidmanifest is as follows

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="info.saltnpepper.ordersmart2.Menu"></activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Rename it then!

Comment: check pakagename info.saltnpepper.ordersmart2.Menu is correct r not?

Comment: Have you initialized your second activity before calling the menu method ?

Comment: post us the intent in the java code

Answer (score 0):

Please change the name of Menu to MenuActivity. Better use Refactor->Rename, so that all occurrences get renamed at the same time